# onClick working in Gecko browsers, but not IE - php, google maps V3

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, onclick

I have built a Google maps app (v3) that uses some php to list database entries onto a page, the user can click an entry, triggering another another list being populated and also the map having markers added. This all works well in Firefox etc, but not in IE.

Reading through here and various forums I realise that onClick is the issue, however I am at a loss as to how to replace it.

```
$query = "SELECT Distinct WID, FirstName, LastName FROM markers ORDER BY LastName asc";
$result = mysql_query ($query);

echo "<select style='font-weight:italic;width:220px;border:1px solid' size=12 id=authName></option>";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option  value=$nt[WID] onclick=searchLocations() title='$nt[LastName]. $nt[FirstName]'>$nt[LastName]. $nt[FirstName]</option>";
}
echo "</select>;";
```

I use the value from [WID] to pass to the rest of the application. http://www.auneheadarts.org.uk/site/projects/wordquest/map_files/writer.php

Answer (score 0):

what do you have set for searchLocations() ?!?

you can try

```
onclick='".searchLocations()."'
```

Comment: searchLocations gets a value from a hidden field further down the page

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="addressInput" value="Okehampton"/>

Comment: here's the whole select section of the page

Comment: or rather the next bit:<input type="hidden" id="addressInput" value="Okehampton"/>
<input type="hidden" id="radiusSelect" value="115" />
<p style="text-align: left">then select a piece of writing</p>
<div id="locationselect">
<select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden" size=12></select>
</div>           When a user selects a line of text it fires the map to add markers and also populates the locationselect box with further text options this won't work in IE because it is all triggered by an onclick.